# Google maps api DirectionsResult object is not getting updating on dragging the route in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a web application in react where I am creating a route between an origin and destination. I have made the route to be draggable. When I drag the starting or destination points the new route is rendered automatically from google's side however the directionsResult object is not getting updated. When I try to console.log the markers longitude and latitude that I just dragged in the onDirectionsChanged event handler it is still showing the initial value that it had. Any idea why?

my app.js code :

```
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  ButtonGroup,
  Flex,
  HStack,
  IconButton,
  Input,
  SkeletonText,
  Text,
} from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { FaLocationArrow, FaTimes } from 'react-icons/fa'

import {
  useJsApiLoader,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  Autocomplete,
  DirectionsRenderer,
} from '@react-google-maps/api'
import { useRef, useState } from 'react'

const center = { lat: 48.8584, lng: 2.2945 }

function App() {
  const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
    libraries: ['places'],
  })

  const [map, setMap] = useState(/** @type google.maps.Map */ (null))
  const [directionsResponse, setDirectionsResponse] = useState(null)
  const [distance, setDistance] = useState('')
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState('')

  /** @type React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement> */
  const originRef = useRef()
  /** @type React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement> */
  const destiantionRef = useRef()

  if (!isLoaded) {
    return <SkeletonText />
  }

  async function calculateRoute() {
    if (originRef.current.value === '' || destiantionRef.current.value === '') {
      return
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService()
    const results = await directionsService.route({
      origin: originRef.current.value,
      destination: destiantionRef.current.value,
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    })
    setDirectionsResponse(results)
    setDistance(results.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text)
    setDuration(results.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text)
  }

  function clearRoute() {
    setDirectionsResponse(null)
    setDistance('')
    setDuration('')
    originRef.current.value = ''
    destiantionRef.current.value = ''
  }

  return (
    <Flex
      position='relative'
      flexDirection='column'
      alignItems='center'
      h='100vh'
      w='100vw'
    >
      <Box position='absolute' left={0} top={0} h='100%' w='100%'>
        {/* Google Map Box */}
        <GoogleMap
          center={center}
          zoom={15}
          mapContainerStyle={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
          options={{
            zoomControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            fullscreenControl: false,
          }}
          onLoad={map => setMap(map)}
        >
          <Marker position={center} />
          {directionsResponse && (
            <DirectionsRenderer directions={directionsResponse} options={{
              draggable:true,
              polylineOptions: {
                strokeOpacity: 12,
                strokeColor: "#1641a6",
                strokeWeight: 12,
              },
            }}
            onDirectionsChanged = {() => {
              console.log("Start latitiude ",directionsResponse.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lat())
              console.log("Start longitude ",directionsResponse.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lng())
            }} />
            
          )}
        </GoogleMap>
      </Box>
      <Box
        p={4}
        borderRadius='lg'
        m={4}
        bgColor='white'
        shadow='base'
        minW='container.md'
        zIndex='1'
      >
        <HStack spacing={2} justifyContent='space-between'>
          <Box flexGrow={1}>
            <Autocomplete>
              <Input type='text' placeholder='Origin' ref={originRef} />
            </Autocomplete>
          </Box>
          <Box flexGrow={1}>
            <Autocomplete>
              <Input
                type='text'
                placeholder='Destination'
                ref={destiantionRef}
              />
            </Autocomplete>
          </Box>

          <ButtonGroup>
            <Button colorScheme='pink' type='submit' onClick={calculateRoute}>
              Calculate Route
            </Button>
            <IconButton
              aria-label='center back'
              icon={<FaTimes />}
              onClick={clearRoute}
            />
          </ButtonGroup>
        </HStack>
        <HStack spacing={4} mt={4} justifyContent='space-between'>
          <Text>Distance: {distance} </Text>
          <Text>Duration: {duration} </Text>
          <IconButton
            aria-label='center back'
            icon={<FaLocationArrow />}
            isRound
            onClick={() => {
              map.panTo(center)
              map.setZoom(15)
            }}
          />
        </HStack>
      </Box>
    </Flex>
  )
}

export default App
```